# How to de-serialize correctly a string pointer?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, serialization, protocol-buffers

relatively new in C++ development in general and serialization specifically.

I have a network application that receives a serialized message using ZeroMQ, checks one of the fields and if has a specific value it forwards the message to another client again using ZeroMQ.

So function A receives the message and stores it to a string pointer:

```
void A()
{
  std::string* serialStr = new string(static_cast<char*>(input->Data()), input->Size());

  if(B(serialStr) == "One") {
    CreateMessage(const_cast<char*>(serialStr->c_str()), serialStr->length(), cleanup, serialStr));
  }
}

cleanup(void *data, void *hint) {delete (string*)hint;}
```

The CreateMessage function is responsible to actually delete serialStr.

How can i call function B without copying the serialStr string? Something like the following is not working:

```
std::string B(std::string* data)
{
  messaging::BMessage* msg = new messaging::BMessage;
  msg->ParseFromString(data);

  return msg->data();
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you using a `std::string*` pointer in 1st place?

Comment: You have memory leaks in your function. And don't worry about copying, most of those will be moves (with a relatively modern C++ compiler) or will be elided.

Comment: Seems that you are internally using "Google protobuf", but the actual question is not clear, where is the problem. Also remember that, `std::string` doesn't copy literally all the times. Refer [**C**opy **O**n **W**rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)

Comment: You can't serialize pointers from one process to another, the memory that it points to only exists in one process. The same address in the other process will contain something completely different.

Comment: What is not working? You leak memory but do you have other problems than that?

Comment: @iammilind copy-on-write is on its way out (none of the latest versions of the mainstream standard libraries do it, and neither do the versions before the latest).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, OK I am not aware if COW is not in practice. But if you refer the wiki link, they take the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#Other_applications_of_copy-on-write) of `std::string` only. Also I remember testing this concept using a small program, where I overloaded the `operator new` and did some copies of `string`. The next `new` was called only when the specific write was happening on a `string`. [Example with C++14](http://ideone.com/oDWvi5). Are you referring to that?

Comment: @iammilind In particular, CoW is (implicitly, I think) disallowed due to changes introduced in C++11.

Comment: @iammilind that example demonstrates nothing. There are no string copies to be made anywhere.

Comment: I use a string* since to my best of understanding is the best way to avoid unnecessary copying if you want to pass-through a ZeroMQ message from one socket to another. 

Receive a message -> get a pointer to it -> pass the pointer to the sending function of ZeroMQ that also will free the memory. By using a regular std:string wont actually create an additional copy?

As for the memory leak, i edited the post to reflect the fact that the CreateMessage function is freeing the allocated memory through the cleanup function

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with references? and how it's can be whithout copying (and copied only address when it's a reference or pointer )

```
    std::string B(std::string& data) 
{
  messaging::BMessage* msg = new messaging::BMessage;
  msg->ParseFromString(data); // here didn't work probably coz this function takes string (with string*  data is address)

  return msg->data();
}
```

Comment: Please fix the leak. And ParseFromString do not take a reference.